# Add a key element for n rows in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like the one shown below.

```
id   |  run_id
--------------
4    |  12345
6    |  12567
10   |  12890
13   |  12450
```

I wish to add a new column say `Key` that will have value 1 for the first n rows and 2 for the next n rows. The result will be like:

```
id   |  run_id  | key
----------------------
4    |  12345   | 1
6    |  12567   | 1
10   |  12890   | 2
13   |  12450   | 2
```

Is it possibile to do the same with PySpark?. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: did the answer I posted below help you? If you are happy with it, would you be OK with accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `zipWithIndex`:

```
# sample rdd
rdd=sc.parallelize([[4,12345], [6,12567], [10,12890], [13,12450]])
# group size for key    
n=2

# add rownumber and then label in batches of size n
rdd=rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda (x, rownum): x+[int(rownum/n)+1])

# convert to dataframe
df=rdd.toDF(schema=['id', 'run_id', 'key'])
df.show(4)
```